# Use results from one SQL statement to do a count in another statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Excel has reached its limits with my data so I'm trying SQL. I am using SQL Server 2019 Express.

I am trying to count the number of unique employee names per GM in the table. Each row of employee is a different project that employee has worked on. For the example below the count for gm1 would be three unique employees and not four as that is the number of records.

```
Employee  GM
--------------
ee1       gm1
ee1       gm1
ee2       gm1
ee3       gm1
ee4       gm2
ee5       gm2
ee6       gm2
...
```

I have these two `SELECT` statements that I'm trying to merge.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EeNumber) AS GMCOUNT
FROM WOWEEs
WHERE GM = '#N/A';

SELECT DISTINCT GM 
FROM WOWEEs;
```

The result should look like

```
GM    Count
------------
gm1   3
gm2   3
```

Comment: Added what the result set should be like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `group by` clause:

```sql
SELECT   gm, COUNT(DISTINCT eenumber)
FROM     wowees
GROUP BY gm
```

Comment: wow that gave me exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much.  I didn't expect the answer to be so fast.  I've been searching Stackoverflow for days.  Thank you Mureinik.